# adding bezierpath inside UIView Container

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I am trying to add a bezierpath(triangle shaped) inside(bottom) an UIView container however I cant seem to get the point correctly of the UIView Container. I am getting this for a result(where is seems a strip of the triangle is showing to the left of the Container View ): [image]

I would like an output such as :

[image]

this is my code thus far :

```
   // adding container to add image
        self.topContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49/255, green:  207/255, blue: 203/255, alpha: 1)
        //        self.topContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.topContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(self.topContainer)


        self.topContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.topContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.55).isActive = true
        self.topContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive =  true

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()                
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.topContainer.frame.size.height))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.topContainer.frame.size.width, y: 222))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.topContainer.frame.size.width, y: self.topContainer.frame.size.height))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.topContainer.frame.size.height))

        UIColor.white.setFill()
        bezierPath.fill()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
        bezierPath.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.topContainer.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: ?? I don't see any of the blue or the red in your first screen shot.

Comment: Its supposed to be white triangle on top of the greenish color on my actual UIView Container as the setFill should be UIColor.white.setFill(). its not showing even though I think i have my lines connection correct?? @matt

Comment: "Its supposed to be white triangle on top of the greenish color" Then it was pretty silly for you to show a red triangle on top of a bluish color!

Comment: its been changed sir @matt

Comment: Yes, _now_. I'm suggesting that you should be pretty careful in how you ask a question at the start. Take the time to make sense and provide the needed information.

Comment: You are manually closing the triangle and calling the .closePath() method. I'd recommend to pick one :-)

Comment: I placed the code inside the ViewDidLoad() @Rob

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently doing this code in `viewDidLoad` of a view controller. You should:

- Remove the `UIColor.white.setFill()` and `path.fill()` code. That only makes sense if drawing within a graphics context (e.g. `draw` method of a `UIView` or within a `UIGraphicsBegin/EndImageContext`). Just construct the `CAShapeLayer` and add it to the view/layer hierarchy, and the OS will take care of drawing/filling it for you.
- Go ahead and create and configure the `CAShapeLayer` in `viewDidLoad`, but move the creation of the `UIBezierPath` and the setting of the `CAShapeLayer`'s `path` to the view controller's [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) method. The `frame` of the view is generally unknown during `viewDidLoad` and is certainly susceptible to being changed (via constraints or autosizing masks). By the time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called, the `frame` is properly configured (and will get called again if the `frame` of the main view changes).

Comment: But maybe we should warn him to use a one-time flag, or he'll be adding the path over and over again, as `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called many times.

Comment: That's why I suggested creating the `CAShapeLayer` once in `viewDidLoad` and add it to the layer's hierarchy once. Then `viewDidLayoutSubviews` simply replaces that shape layer's `path` with a new `UIBezierPath`. It avoids that problem. But, yes, if you did something like adding a new `CAShapeLayer` each time in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, then you can get in a world of hurt.

Comment: Hi, @Rob I did exactly what you said, but it seems that now the path or shape is not being created at all even though now as mentioned, i can see the container view height and width.

Comment: @Aboogie - Without seeing what you did, I can't comment. But see this for an example: https://github.com/robertmryan/PolygonViewDemo